# pg_agent not executing the query

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I am trying to create a task job with pg_agent. I have created a new job, schedule, and step. They are all enabled. In my step, I have such a query to get run:

```
DELETE FROM "ID: 889197824 CH: 0006 Messdaten" t  
   USING (
   SELECT "Zeit" FROM "ID: 889197824 CH: 0006 Messdaten" WHERE "Zeit" < ts2oadate(now() - (interval '3 Months'))
   ) d  
LEFT   JOIN ( 
   SELECT min("Zeit") AS "Zeit" 
   FROM   "ID: 889197824 CH: 0006 Messdaten" 
   WHERE  "Zeit" < ts2oadate(now() - (interval '3 Months')) 
   GROUP  BY date_trunc('hours',oadate2ts("Zeit")) 

   ) x USING ("Zeit") 
WHERE  x."Zeit" IS NULL 
AND    d."Zeit" = t."Zeit";
```

After checking event viewer of the pg_agent service, I found out such an error:

```
Failed to create new connection for connection string 'user=postgres host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db':fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

This is the pgpass.conf

```
localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:xxxx
```

Do you have any idea what would be the problem?

Some more info:

This is job

[image]

This is schedule

[image]

And this is step

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved the problem by changing the pgpass.conf in the path:

```
postgres\AppData\Roaming\postgresql
```

to

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:xxx
```

Before I was trying to change the wrong pgpass.conf which is in the path:

```
pcUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql
```

I hope, it helps someone else